# Can BigQuery use a wildcard with external tables based on CSV files in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Can I query using the wildcard feature in BigQuery from external tables stored as CSVs on Google Cloud Storage?

The CSV files are in a Google Cloud Storage bucket and the files have different partitions / chunks of the data, like this

```
org_score_p1
org_score_p2
...
org_score_p99
```

Also, I expect that the number of files in bucket will continue to grow, so new files will be added with the same naming scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. However, you need make sure that

- your Google Cloud Storage bucket is configured as multi-regional
- your bucket's multi-regional location is set to the same place as the one where you are running your BigQuery jobs.

Otherwise you will get an error / exception similar to this one:

```
Cannot read and write in different locations: source: US-EAST4, destination: US
```